# How to use.htaccess and .htpasswd to protect a specific web page in the website

Tags: html, .htaccess, .htpasswd

Hi I've currently got a website for a restaurant where I need to have the staff.html page protected by .htaccess and .htpasswrd but I'm unsure how to do this as my main page is idex.html and has a link in the nav bar to the staff.html page.

Below is my .htaccess code:

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Restricted access"
AuthUserFile "\Users\tayla\OneDrive\Documents\BIT607\HaukaiA3\web.htpasswd"
Require valid-user
```

All of my files are saved within the same file as seen below:

```
"\Users\tayla\OneDrive\Documents\BIT607\HaukaiA3\web.htpasswd"
```

If anyone can help me understand how I can protect a specific page like my staff.html that would be muchly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```sh
# for URI=/staff.html set an env variable PROTECTED=1
SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI "/staff\.html" PROTECTED

# allow all pages but put PROTECTED=1 behind basic auth
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Restricted access"
AuthUserFile "\Users\tayla\OneDrive\Documents\BIT607\HaukaiA3\web.htpasswd"
Require valid-user
Satisfy    any
Order      Allow,Deny
Allow from all
Deny from env=PROTECTED
```

Comment: Thank you that seems to make sense but I'm not getting anything coming up at all? Where would I be going wrong for this to be happening? Do I need to organize my files in anyway?

Comment: `web.htpasswd` should not have read access for others and world. Also check your Apache error log

Comment: It seems you are on Windows. Please check on net how to set right permissions for htpasswd file

Comment: do you mean i should put them in a separate file?

Comment: Nothing to do in a separate file except `web.htpasswd`

Comment: when I go onto my live server it and click on the link to staff.html it comes up with: Cannot GET /web/staff.html. Do you know why this would be?

Comment: `Cannot GET /web/staff.html.` is unrelated with the password protection code I posted